# Converting inputStream to FileInputStream?

Tags: android, inputstream, fileinputstream

I am in a problem - i need to read SecretKey from Android APK (e.g. key.keystore), for my app it has to be read as a FileInputStream, but from assets I am getting only inputStream. How to convert inputStream to FileInputStream? Or is there any other way, how to acces file from e.g. resources as a fileInputStream?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why do you need a FileInputStream specifically? In general, you don't have to care about the underlying implementation of the InputStream, you just read from it. Maybe *your* implementation should be InputStream agnostic.

Comment: You are right, 16hours of programming in a row make me mad :-)

Answer (score 4):

I think you are referring to [AssetManager.open()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open) that returns an InputStream. There is no need to "convert" it to a FileInputStream, just get the reference to the InputStream and use it (wrap it in a BufferedInputStream if you want).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is possible because a FileInputStream is simply a InputStream for Files. It does the job of getting an InputStream from the defined file for you, after that you're working with a normal InputStream.

Android already did this Job for you. So why do you need a FileInputStream?

Comment: You may want a FileInputStream as you want to know the length of the file unless there is a way I haven't yet found.

Comment: I don't see any `getLength()`-method on FileInputStream, so not sure what you're getting at. Also, if it's an asset that *you* put into the APK, you know it's file size. The FileInputStream is just a convenient way of getting a InputStream (to read the files content) from a "physical" file.

Comment: Sorry @Lukas-Knuth, I was confusing myself! However I am using the FileInputStream of an uncompressed resource in order to read in its data in full:
AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.myresource);
FileInputStream fis = afd.createInputStream();

data = new byte[(int)afd.getLength()];

DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
dis.readFully(data);
dis.close();